# Spring MVC Post request - only passing the ID of object to create reference to it?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following client `Entity` which has a trainer object as a field:

**Entity:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CLIENT")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public class Client {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
    
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
        private Trainer trainer;

        public Trainer() {}
        }

}
```

**POST Request:**

```
@PostMapping("/clients")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createClient(@RequestBody Client client) {
    Client createdClient = clientRepository.save(client);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(createdClient);
}
```

Whoever when I post e.g. this request:

```
{
"name": "New PT Client Steve",
"trainer": 3
 }
```

The object is created in my DB but trainer field is **null**, even though 3 corresponds to a valid trainer id.

How can I solve this? Do I need to provide the full `trainer` object instead of Id eventhough I have the `@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json and JPA annotations don't really interact with each other.  To JPA, you have an empty object that it doesn't know how to reference or interact with.

1. you need to make Trainer a top level class annotated with @Entity.  JPA says

> "The entity class must be a top-level class."

2. Trainer needs to have an ID of some sort.  otherwise ManyToOne won't be able to refer to it.
3. You will probably need a custom setter of some sort. Possibly:

> ```
> @JsonSetter("trainer)
> // assumes your ID is int or Integer
> public void setTrainerFromJson(Integer id) {
>   if (id != null) {
>      this.trainer = trainerRepository.findById(id);
>   } else {
>     this.trainer = null;
>   }
> }
> ```

trainer can still be null if the trainer has not already been created, and you would need to inject the trainer repository into the client class (there may be timing issues during JPA scanning and creation)